# SPA refresh when assets have changed?

Tags: javascript, single-page-application, react-router-v4

I have written an SPA which caches all its assets like `bundle-1234.js` which are required in the `index.html`. I'm wondering that when the `bundle-1234.js` is downloaded, cached and executed how does the app ever refresh when the bundle changed to `bundle-9876.js`?

I'm using `react-router-dom` do the routing of my SPA, so a route change is not a page refresh. Beware that the app will not be manually refreshed by the user.

**How do you tell a SPA to refesh its assets when the page doesn't refresh?**

Comment: How and when are you changing the bundle.js? Assets to be updated should be referenced in your state or props.

Comment: By uploading it to my server when I deploy an update, don't know how to be more specific. How would I check if the assets in my state are not matching the newly deployed assets?

Comment: If you are deploying an update to your server, why would a client app be continuously running? Why would there be no refresh or reload?

Comment: If you are assuming a "forever-running" client app, why don't you just write in a timed refresh to the application to 'check if there are any changes'

Comment: It is an app which runs on IOS / android devices in a kiosk and is locked to the screen. Updating this should not take an employee to run around and update all X amount of Ipads when an update happens :)

Comment: I would recommend writing in a timed refresh function to your app. You can decide what is a reasonable time interval to refresh the app.