# Forcing refresh of cached JS in SPA (reactJS) that changes between requests using react router

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack, react-router, react-router-dom

I have come to the conclusion that my SPA using reactJS coupled with react router (`react-router-dom 5`, a client side routing service) CAN ONLY get a newly deployed javascript file IF IT is through a refresh. There is no other way. Am I wrong?

**Scenario:**

1. User is on the homepage
2. A new JS bundle gets deployed. (I am using webpack and using the following format: `app.[hash].js` as per [webpacks's caching documentation.](https://webpack.js.org/guides/caching/) This is then referenced by index.html e.g. `<script src="app.dc1abe70ccbf1b703e01.js">`)
3. User now clicks on another link (new route) BUT the old JS still shows (even though there is new code available)
4. Only when a user does a refresh of the page, does the new code show. (Http status 200 and then 304 on each subsequent refresh until JS changes again which will result in another 200 and so on)

Now, I have gone though several threads, **but I am still not clear on how to *implement a simple solution* to get a freshly deployed JS file *WITHOUT a refresh* from the back end for an SPA (ReactJS) using react router that replaces a cached version of the JS file between requests.**

**My understanding**

When you use react router, a route is loaded within the SPA when clicked (client side) without requesting any html or js from the back end because there is no need to. i.e. the loading is instant because it's meant to be an SPA. This makes sense because as I said, when the app is loaded the first time, `app.[hash].js` is downloaded and subsequently referenced.

I have seen many other threads offering various solutions like:

1. forcing the server to issue a new JS file: `script.js?v=1` This however is a hack and you will end up with multiple versions of js files in your browser as per [this.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32414/how-can-i-force-clients-to-refresh-javascript-files) Besides, I am using routes (essentially, links managed through react router). I think `script.js?v=1` is for individual links. I am also using webpacks format for my js references: `app.[hash].js`
2. Others have asked the same question regarding caching and SPA's but never received replies like [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46002676/spa-refresh-when-assets-have-changed) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61189377/how-to-refresh-in-spa-react-vue)

**Conclusion and goal**

According to this comment: `This is expected behaviour and until user will not refreshes his page, new changes will not be loaded – Zohaib Ijaz Apr 13 at 14:02` from this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61189377/how-to-refresh-in-spa-react-vue)

*MOSTLY everything I have researched does not speak specifically to ReactJS PLUS react-router-dom. They mention versioning js files with a `?ver=xyz` but that is for individual links I believe, NOT a router with routes. Some others mention using `app.[hash].js` but then stop short to explaining what to do next.*

**EVERYTHING I have researched leads me to believe that in order to see new JS changes the next time a react router link is clicked, my ReactJS SPA with react-router can only see these new changes if it is refreshed. And if so, then there is NO SOLUTION but to hope the customer will refresh the page (because this IS the practical solution)?**

p.s I am using express server

Comment: You can show a small popup in the app saying "A newer version is available..." and ask if they want to stay or go to newer version. If user clicks yes, reload the window for the new version

Comment: @ObnoxiousNerd  so are you agreeing with my conclusion? That there is NO solution but to refresh as per what I have described?

Comment: You can eject and set skipWaiting to true (assuming sw is made using sw-precache or workbox)

Comment: https://dev.to/flexdinesh/cache-busting-a-react-app-22lk

Comment: @obnoxiousNerd I've seen this link and it doesn't pertain to this scenario. In the link, it says: "When the App is mounted, fetch meta.json and compare the current version with the latest version in the server." The key here is WHEN the app is mounted, it will check for a stale version of the JS. My app IS ALREADY mounted. The user just clicks on a link between deploys. I.e. the app is not mounted again. Like I said, I am using the versioning hash on my JS file so it gets the latest file upon a refresh anyway. BUT that's not the point. How will it get new JS without refreshing??

Comment: this might help you : https://developers.google.com/web/tools/workbox/guides/advanced-recipes .. but its a custom service worker through Workbox